# ASP.NET Repeater: Is it possible to display on the first item one element, but not for the rest of the items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_RatingQuestions_Individuals" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label CssClass="bold center" ID="Label1" runat="server"     Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Question")%>' />
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_RatingAnswers_Individuals" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answers") %>'>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="8">
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UserID")%>' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            </table>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

This is my repeater. I have 2 classes:

```
public class cQuestion
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<cAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}
public class cAnswer
{
    public string Answer { get ; set; }
    public uint Value { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Without having to creating some other generic list of an object, would it be possible to display for the first record the UserID, in the nested Repeater, but for the rest of them not show the UserID? If it's not possible then fine I'll just go with my alternate solutions. I just wanted to know if this is possible without having to add new properties or new classes.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yup, just add a function call to your ItemTemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this is off a little (I haven't used Repeaters in a  very long time).  Have you tried calling a Code Behind function from within the repeater?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_RatingQuestions_Individuals" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label CssClass="bold center" ID="Label1" runat="server"     Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Question")%>' />

        <%# SetShowIDToTrue() %>

        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_RatingAnswers_Individuals" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answers") %>'>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="8">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# ShouldThisBeWrittenOut(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UserID"))%>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in your code behind

```
private bool ShowUID { get; set; }

private int? ShouldThisBeWrittenOut(int UserID)
{
    if (ShowUID) {
        ShowUID = false;
        return UserID;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private void SetShowIDToTrue()
{
    ShowUID = true;
}
```

Comment: Just tested it out. This is a start, but I have multiple users. I am guessing I did not make that clear. For each first item in each nested repeater.

Comment: I changed the example a little... Oh wait, I get it.  The principle still applies, however you'll have to change the logic to reset the `ShowUID`... I'm gunna take a look...

Comment: I made another edit. notice the `<%# SetShowIDToTrue() %>` in the outer repeater.

Comment: Oh my. This isn't working either. I'm wondering if I should just give up here and go with my alternate solution. I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: I can't write your code for you, But I can say that this WILL work. You just need to use some creative thinking. The process is simple.  Set the bool to true for the first time the UID is to be shown, then set it to false until you need it to be true again.

Comment: No I know. I appreciate it. I was just going through the debugger, and it binds each element once, so setting the ShowUID to true never occurs. I'm going to play with this though. Thanks.

Comment: no problems, Like I said, I haven't used a Repeater in a very long time. I've been using MVC where I have full control of the loop.

Comment: Yeah. I hear you there. I just got back onto this project to modify some things. This project is going to be eventually converted into silverlight mvvm. ugh can't wait, because this code is just getting so ugly.